# Odoo 10 - python 3 setup.py install got NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I m new to `python`.

I m installing bitnami odoo in my google compute engine `VM` instance debian linux.

as per the below `URL` I tried.

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/odoo/administration/upgrade/#migrate-data-to-the-new-odoo-installation

```
sudo python3 setup.py install --prefix=/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo --install-lib=/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib
```

When I run above in my `SSH` terminal. I got issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    execfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'odoo', 'release.py'))  # Load release variables
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

I tried to change `execfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'odoo', 'release.py'))` to `exec(open(join(dirname(__file__), 'odoo', 'release.py').read()))`

But not working, Here is my `setup.py` script.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import os
    import re
    from glob import glob
    from setuptools import find_packages, setup
    from os.path import join, dirname
    execfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'odoo', 'release.py'))  # Load release variables
    lib_name = 'odoo'
    def py2exe_datafiles():
        data_files = {}
        data_files['Microsoft.VC90.CRT'] = glob('C:\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*')
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('odoo'):
            for filename in filenames:
                 if not re.match(r'.*(\.pyc|\.pyo|\~)$', filename):
                    data_files.setdefault(root, []).append(join(root, filename))
        import babel
        data_files['babel/localedata'] = glob(join(dirname(babel.__file__), 'localedata', '*'))
        others = ['global.dat', 'numbers.py', 'support.py', 'plural.py']
        data_files['babel'] = map(lambda f: join(dirname(babel.__file__), f), others)
        others = ['frontend.py', 'mofile.py']
        data_files['babel/messages'] = map(lambda f: join(dirname(babel.__file__), 'messages', f), others)
        import pytz
        tzdir = dirname(pytz.__file__)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk(join(tzdir, 'zoneinfo')):
            base = join('pytz', root[len(tzdir) + 1:])
            data_files[base] = [join(root, f) for f in filenames]
        import docutils
        import passlib
        import reportlab
        import requests
        data_mapping = ((docutils, 'docutils'),
                        (passlib, 'passlib'),
                        (reportlab, 'reportlab'),
                        (requests, 'requests'))
        for mod, datadir in data_mapping:
            basedir = dirname(mod.__file__)
            for root, _, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
                base = join(datadir, root[len(basedir) + 1:])
                data_files[base] = [join(root, f)
                                    for f in filenames
                                    if not f.endswith(('.py', '.pyc', '.pyo'))]
        return data_files.items()

        def py2exe_options():
        if os.name == 'nt':
            import py2exe
            return {
                'console': [
                    {'script': 'odoo-bin', 'icon_resources': [
                        (1, join('setup', 'win32', 'static', 'pixmaps', 'openerp-icon.ico'))
                    ]},
                ],
                'options': {
                    'py2exe': {
                        'skip_archive': 1,
                        'optimize': 0,  # Keep the assert running as the integrated tests rely on them.
                        'dist_dir': 'dist',
                        'packages': [
                            'asynchat', 'asyncore',
                            'BeautifulSoup',
                            'commands',
                            'dateutil',
                            'decimal',
                            'decorator',
                            'docutils',
                            'email',
                            'encodings',
                            'HTMLParser',
                            'imaplib',
                            'jinja2',
                            'lxml', 'lxml._elementpath', 'lxml.builder', 'lxml.etree', 'lxml.objectify',
                            'mako',
                            'markupsafe',
                            'mock',
                            'ofxparse',
                            'odoo',
                            'openid',
                            'passlib',
                            'PIL',
                            'poplib',
                            'psutil',
                            'pychart',
                            'pydot',
                            'pyparsing',
                            'pyPdf',
                            'pytz',
                            'reportlab',
                            'requests',
                            'select',
                            'smtplib',
                            'suds',
                            'uuid',
                            'vatnumber',
                            'vobject',
                            'win32service', 'win32serviceutil',
                            'xlrd',
                            'xlsxwriter',
                            'xlwt',
                            'xml', 'xml.dom',
                            'yaml',
                        ],
                        'excludes': ['Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'tcl'],
                    }
                },
                'data_files': py2exe_datafiles()
            }
        else:
            return {}

            setup(
        name='odoo',
        version=version,
        description=description,
        long_description=long_desc,
        url=url,
        author=author,
        author_email=author_email,
        classifiers=filter(None, classifiers.split('\n')),
        license=license,
        scripts=['setup/odoo'],
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_dir={'%s' % lib_name: 'odoo'},
        include_package_data=True,
        install_requires=[
            'babel >= 1.0',
            'decorator',
            'docutils',
            'feedparser',
            'gevent',
            'Jinja2',
            'lxml',  # windows binary http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
            'mako',
            'mock',
            'ofxparse',
            'passlib',
            'pillow',  # windows binary http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
            'psutil',  # windows binary code.google.com/p/psutil/downloads/list
            'psycogreen',
            'psycopg2 >= 2.2',
            'python-chart',
            'pydot',
            'pyparsing',
            'pypdf',
            'pyserial',
            'python-dateutil',
            'python-ldap',  # optional
            'python-openid',
            'pytz',
            'pyusb >= 1.0.0b1',
            'pyyaml',
            'qrcode',
            'reportlab',  # windows binary pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab
            'requests',
            'suds-jurko',
            'vatnumber',
            'vobject',
            'werkzeug',
            'xlsxwriter',
            'xlwt',
        ],
        extras_require={
            'SSL': ['pyopenssl'],
        },
        tests_require=[
            'mock',
        ],
        **py2exe_options()
    )
```

In the above `setup.py` how to fix execfile to exec

EDIT:

I tried using `python 2.7` But I got this issues

```
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo --install-lib=/opt/bitn
ami/apps/odoo/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:333: UserWarning: Normalizing '10.0-20190219' to '10.0.post20190219'
  normalized_version,
running install
Checking .pth file support in /opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH
You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
    /opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/
and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:
    ''
Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:
* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files
* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)
* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:
  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations
Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

How to set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files? I read the details, got confused.

I appreciate those who help to solve this.

UPDATE:

i tried as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806281/1533582

Here is the installation [Log [1]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LaDlIQSMsZYUJGX5chvRdgZW9GjaBQa1ss4sIqDvTg8/edit#gid=288747620)

After this installation. opened this url in my browser http://my-ipaddress:8069/odoo

But I got output like this

[image]

What is missing in the above odoo installation?

**UPDATE 2:**

I re tried odoo installation as per the reply. Here is the installation [log [2]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LaDlIQSMsZYUJGX5chvRdgZW9GjaBQa1ss4sIqDvTg8/edit#gid=1382537064)

Also Created firewall rules in Google Cloud Platform VPC network

```
Name    Type    Targets Filters Protocols / ports   Action  Priority    Network
odoo-latest Ingress http-server IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:7575 Allow 1000 default
```

Opened this url in browser http://my-ip-address:7575/odoo_latest

But I got same issue only. Nothing opening.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 is not supported by Odoo 10. For Odoo 10 use Python 2.7

From Odoo 11 only supports Python 3.X !

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# Script for installing Odoo V10 on Ubuntu 16.04, 15.04, 14.04 (could be used for other version too)
# Author: Muhammad Faizal NS
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script will install Odoo on your Ubuntu 14.04 server. It can install multiple Odoo instances
# in one Ubuntu because of the different xmlrpc_ports
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Make a new file:
# sudo nano odoo-install.sh
# Place this content in it and then make the file executable:
# sudo chmod +x odoo-install.sh
# Execute the script to install Odoo:
# ./odoo-install
################################################################################

##fixed parameters
#odoo
OE_USER="odoo_latest"
OE_HOME="/opt/odoo/$OE_USER"
OE_HOME_EXT="/opt/odoo/$OE_USER/${OE_USER}-server"
#The default port where this Odoo instance will run under (provided you use the command -c in the terminal)
#Set to true if you want to install it, false if you don't need it or have it already installed.
INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF="True"
#Set the default Odoo port (you still have to use -c /etc/odoo-server.conf for example to use this.)
OE_PORT="7575"
#Choose the Odoo version which you want to install. For example: 10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0 or saas-6. When using 'trunk' the master version will be installed.
#IMPORTANT! This script contains extra libraries that are specifically needed for Odoo 10.0
OE_VERSION="10.0"
# Set this to True if you want to install Odoo 10 Enterprise!
IS_ENTERPRISE="False"
#set the superadmin password
OE_SUPERADMIN="admin"
OE_CONFIG="${OE_USER}-server"

##
###  WKHTMLTOPDF download links
## === Ubuntu Trusty x64 & x32 === (for other distributions please replace these two links,
## in order to have correct version of wkhtmltox installed, for a danger note refer to 
## https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html#deb ):
WKHTMLTOX_X64=https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
WKHTMLTOX_X32=https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
#--------------------------------------------------
# Update Server
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Update Server ----"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install PostgreSQL Server
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Install PostgreSQL Server ----"
sudo apt-get install postgresql -y

echo -e "\n---- Creating the ODOO PostgreSQL User  ----"
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s $OE_USER" 2> /dev/null || true

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install Dependencies
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Install tool packages ----"
sudo apt-get install wget git python-pip gdebi-core -y

echo -e "\n---- Install python packages ----"
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-feedparser python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-openid python-psycopg2 python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi python-docutils python-psutil python-mock python-unittest2 python-jinja2 python-pypdf python-decorator python-requests python-passlib python-pil -y python-suds

echo -e "\n---- Install python libraries ----"
sudo pip install gdata psycogreen ofxparse XlsxWriter xlrd

echo -e "\n--- Install other required packages"
sudo apt-get install node-clean-css -y
sudo apt-get install node-less -y
sudo apt-get install python-gevent -y

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install Wkhtmltopdf if needed
#--------------------------------------------------
if [ $INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF = "True" ]; then
  echo -e "\n---- Install wkhtml and place shortcuts on correct place for ODOO 10 ----"
  #pick up correct one from x64 & x32 versions:
  if [ "`getconf LONG_BIT`" == "64" ];then
      _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X64
  else
      _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X32
  fi
  sudo wget $_url
  sudo gdebi --n `basename $_url`
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
else
  echo "Wkhtmltopdf isn't installed due to the choice of the user!"
fi

echo -e "\n---- Create ODOO system user ----"
sudo adduser --system --quiet --shell=/bin/bash --home=$OE_HOME --gecos 'ODOO' --group $OE_USER
#The user should also be added to the sudo'ers group.
sudo adduser $OE_USER sudo

echo -e "\n---- Create Log directory ----"
sudo mkdir /var/log/$OE_USER
sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /var/log/$OE_USER

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install ODOO
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n==== Installing ODOO Server ===="
sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo $OE_HOME_EXT/

if [ $IS_ENTERPRISE = "True" ]; then
    # Odoo Enterprise install!
    echo -e "\n--- Create symlink for node"
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
    sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise"
    sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons"

    GITHUB_RESPONSE=$(sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch 10.0 https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons" 2>&1)
    while [[ $GITHUB_RESPONSE == *"Authentication"* ]]; do
        echo "------------------------WARNING------------------------------"
        echo "Your authentication with Github has failed! Please try again."
        printf "In order to clone and install the Odoo enterprise version you \nneed to be an offical Odoo partner and you need access to\nhttp://github.com/odoo/enterprise.\n"
        echo "TIP: Press ctrl+c to stop this script."
        echo "-------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo " "
        GITHUB_RESPONSE=$(sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch 10.0 https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons" 2>&1)
    done

    echo -e "\n---- Added Enterprise code under $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons ----"
    echo -e "\n---- Installing Enterprise specific libraries ----"
    sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
    sudo npm install -g less
    sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
fi

echo -e "\n---- Create custom module directory ----"
sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/custom"
sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/custom/addons"

echo -e "\n---- Setting permissions on home folder ----"
sudo chown -R $OE_USER:$OE_USER $OE_HOME/*

echo -e "* Create server config file"
sudo cp $OE_HOME_EXT/debian/odoo.conf /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo chmod 640 /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf

echo -e "* Change server config file"
sudo sed -i s/"db_user = .*"/"db_user = $OE_USER"/g /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo sed -i s/"; admin_passwd.*"/"admin_passwd = $OE_SUPERADMIN"/g /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo su root -c "echo '[options]' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
sudo su root -c "echo 'logfile = /var/log/$OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG$1.log' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
if [  $IS_ENTERPRISE = "True" ]; then
    sudo su root -c "echo 'addons_path=$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons,$OE_HOME_EXT/addons' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
else
    sudo su root -c "echo 'addons_path=$OE_HOME_EXT/addons,$OE_HOME/custom/addons' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
fi

echo -e "* Create startup file"
sudo su root -c "echo '#!/bin/sh' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
sudo su root -c "echo 'sudo -u $OE_USER $OE_HOME_EXT/openerp-server --config=/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
sudo chmod 755 $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh

#--------------------------------------------------
# Adding ODOO as a deamon (initscript)
#--------------------------------------------------

echo -e "* Create init file"
cat <<EOF > ~/$OE_CONFIG
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: $OE_CONFIG
# Required-Start: \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Required-Stop: \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Should-Start: \$network
# Should-Stop: \$network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Enterprise Business Applications
# Description: ODOO Business Applications
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=$OE_HOME_EXT/odoo-bin
NAME=$OE_CONFIG
DESC=$OE_CONFIG

# Specify the user name (Default: odoo).
USER=$OE_USER

# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/openerp-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"

# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/\${NAME}.pid

# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
DAEMON_OPTS="-c \$CONFIGFILE"
[ -x \$DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f \$CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0
checkpid() {
[ -f \$PIDFILE ] || return 1
pid=\`cat \$PIDFILE\`
[ -d /proc/\$pid ] && return 0
return 1
}

case "\${1}" in
start)
echo -n "Starting \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
--exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--oknodo
echo "\${NAME}."
;;

restart|force-reload)
echo -n "Restarting \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--oknodo
sleep 1
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
--exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
*)
N=/etc/init.d/\$NAME
echo "Usage: \$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
exit 1
;;

esac
exit 0
EOF

echo -e "* Security Init File"
sudo mv ~/$OE_CONFIG /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
sudo chown root: /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG

echo -e "* Change default xmlrpc port"
sudo su root -c "echo 'xmlrpc_port = $OE_PORT' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"

echo -e "* Start ODOO on Startup"
sudo update-rc.d $OE_CONFIG defaults

echo -e "* Starting Odoo Service"
sudo su root -c "/etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG start"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Done! The Odoo server is up and running. Specifications:"
echo "Port: $OE_PORT"
echo "User service: $OE_USER"
echo "User PostgreSQL: $OE_USER"
echo "Code location: $OE_USER"
echo "Addons folder: $OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG/addons/"
echo "Start Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG start"
echo "Stop Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG stop"
echo "Restart Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG restart"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
```

Save the above in a file and save with an extension of '.sh'. Then open the terminal from where you saved the file. Then type sudo bash .sh

Hope this will work. Don't forget to put tick mark if this works. Also give me an upvote too.

Comment: thanks, Pablo Escobar, I tried with Python 2.7. But another issue set up the installation directory has not supported ".pth" files got, I edited my post. Plz help me to solve this

Comment: @Sattanathan , edited the answer. Hope this will fix your issue. Don't forget to put tick mark.

Comment: Pablo Escobar,Updated my question, I gave the odoo installation Log, Plz check and help me. Odoo not opening in my browser.

Comment: What is the result after removing that odoo from the url ?

Comment: URL without odoo  bitnami Redmine loading.

Comment: sudo pkill -f odoo
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start

Then try !

Comment: sudo pkill -f odoo ,~# sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start
Starting odoo-server: odoo-server. I did, But Same output in URL

Comment: Server started, But odoo not opening, Same issue only

Comment: Pablo Escobar, Any updates on this, Plz help me to solve this

Comment: I appreciate those help to solve this, Maybe I did wrong. Bitnami - Redmine installed in VM Linux, In that Same Instance ran Odoo, Server started. But open URL like this https://my-ipaddress:8069/odoo, not opening. Plz, help me.

Comment: @Sattanathan , do this once more and tell.

Copy the above code in .sh extension file. Bash it from terminal. try to access the odoo_latest server through the port 7575.

Comment: pablo-Escobar,I tried again. Plz, see my edited UPDATE 2. I gave the installation log[2]. But URL nothing opening